# Style "create" view

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, user-experience

I have created a view where the user can insert his details for city, title, description and submit it using json with http post to my gae python backend.

But the style does not look good. I am not very good with CSS. I would like it to look "nicer" or more aligned. Sorry if I am being vague but if you have a look at the form it is practically unstyled.

[image]

To begin with, I would like "type your text here" to be more like a textbox and more to the right. How can I achieve that?

My code for the view:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Alert, AsyncStorage, Dimensions, Picker, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Input} from 'react-native-elements'

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class Buttons extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        if (AsyncStorage.getItem('name')) {
            name = AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
        }


        if (AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_id')) {
            auth_id = AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_id');
        }


        this.state = {
            name: name,
            auth_id: auth_id,
            country: '',
            category: '',
            region: '',
            city: '',
            title: 'lorem',
            text: 'ipsum',
            options: {
                "4699201": "Kumbakonam",
                "4699202": "Madurai",
                "4700196": "Chengalpattu",
                "4700197": "Coonoor",
                "4693193": "Tiruchirappalli",
                "4700198": "Kanchipuram",
                "4700199": "Pudukkottai",
                "4703196": "Thoothukkudi",
                "4701199": "Karur",
                "4691203": "Avadi",
                "4691202": "Ambattur",
                "4697199": "Thanjavur",
                "4697198": "Chennai",
                "4691205": "Other city",
                "4696196": "Salem",
                "4691204": "Vellore",
                "4701198": "Erode",
                "4701200": "Tiruvannamalai",
                "4694193": "Arakonam",
                "4692202": "Hosur",
                "4692203": "Pollachi",
                "4702196": "Dindigul",
                "4702197": "Tambaram",
                "4695201": "Cuddalore",
                "4695202": "Tiruppur",
                "4704192": "Coimbatore",
                "4702198": "Tirunelveli",
                "4676202": "Namakkal",
                "4676201": "Nagercoil"
            }
        };
    }

    selectCountry(val) {
        this.setState({country: val});
    }

    setTitle(val) {
        this.setState({title: val});
    }

    setCategory(val) {
        this.setState({category: val});
    }

    setCity(val) {
        this.setState({city: val});
    }

    setText(val) {
        this.setState({text: val});
    }

    selectRegion(val) {
        this.setState({region: val});
        fetch('https://www.koolbusiness.com/cities/insert/api', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "region_id": val,
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setCities(responseJson);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    setCities = (value) => {
        this.setState({'options': value});
    };
    setName = (value) => {
        this.setState({'name': value});
    };
    onPressLearnMore = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("auth_id").then((value) => {

            fetch('https://www.koolbusiness.com/api/add', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "auth_id": value,
                    "title": this.state.title,
                    "text": this.state.text,
                    "city": this.state.city,
                    "category": this.state.category,
                }),
            }).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    //  this.setCities(responseJson);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });


            Alert.alert(
                'Thank you ' + this.state.name,
                'Your ad was posted',
                [

                    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                    {text: 'Logout', onPress: () => AsyncStorage.clear()},
                ],
                {cancelable: false}
            );

        });


    };

    componentDidMount() {

        AsyncStorage.getItem("name").then((value) => {

            this.state.name = value;

        });

        fetch('https://www.koolbusiness.com/cities/insert/api', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "region_id": "4701188",
                "password": this.state.password,
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setCities(responseJson);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.contentView}>
                    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                        <Icon color="white" name="rocket" size={62}/>
                        <Text style={styles.heading}>Create your ad</Text>
                    </View>

                    <Text>Pick a Category</Text>
                    <Picker selectedValue={this.state.category}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setCategory(itemValue)}
                    >


                        <Picker.Item label="Houses" value="1020"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Apartments" value="1010"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Vacation homes" value="1030"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Offices" value="1050"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Land" value="1080"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Flatmates/Paying Guest" value="1100"/>


                        <Picker.Item label="Cars" value="2010"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Motorcycles" value="2030"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Accessories &amp; parts" value="2040"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Trucks" value="2080"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Other vehicles" value="2070"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Home &amp; Personal items" value="js"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Home &amp; Garden" value="3040"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Clothing" value="3050"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="For Kids (Toys &amp; Clothes)" value="3030"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Jewelry &amp; Watches" value="3060"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Leisure, Sports &amp; hobby" value="js"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Hobbies" value="4010"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Sports &amp; Bicycles" value="4020"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Movies, Books &amp; Magazines" value="4040"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Pets" value="4030"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Tickets" value="4090"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Art &amp; Collectibles" value="4060"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Music &amp; Instruments" value="4070"/>

                        <Picker.Item label="Computers &amp; Accessories" value="5030"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="TV, Audio, Video, Cameras" value="5020"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Cellphones &amp; gadgets" value="5010"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Video games &amp; consoles" value="5040"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Jobs &amp; Services" value="js"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Job offers" value="6010"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Resumes" value="6020"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Services" value="6030"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Classes" value="6040"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Professional/Office equipment" value="6090"/>

                        <Picker.Item label="Other" value="7010"/>
                    </Picker>
                    <Text>Pick a Region</Text>

                    <Picker selectedValue={this.state.region}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.selectRegion(itemValue)}
                    >

                        <Picker.Item label="Andaman &amp; Nicobar Islands" value="4703187"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Andhra Pradesh" value="4694186"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Arunachal Pradesh" value="4699188"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Assam" value="4692186"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Bihar" value="4702186"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Chandigarh" value="4698185"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Chhattisgarh" value="4676188"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Dadra &amp; Nagar Haveli" value="4691190"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Daman &amp; Diu" value="4704183"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Delhi" value="4699183"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Goa" value="4702187"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Gujarat" value="4691189"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Haryana" value="4700186"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Himachal Pradesh" value="4703185"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Jammu &amp; Kashmir" value="4694187"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Jharkhand" value="4699189"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Karnataka" value="4701185"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Kerala" value="4695189"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Lakshadweep" value="4700189"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Madhya Pradesh" value="4697186"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Maharashtra" value="4694184"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Manipur" value="4700187"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Meghalaya" value="4703186"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Mizoram" value="4698184"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Nagaland" value="4692187"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Orissa" value="4696185"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Pondicherry" value="4676189"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Punjab" value="4693185"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Rajasthan" value="4701186"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Sikkim" value="4701187"/>


                        <Picker.Item label="Tamil Nadu" value="4701188"/>

                        <Picker.Item label="Telangana" value="4984687332163584"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Tripura" value="4697187"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Uttaranchal" value="4699190"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="Uttar Pradesh" value="4692188"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="West Bengal" value="4700188"/>
                    </Picker>
                    <Text>Pick a City</Text>

                    <Picker selectedValue={this.state.city}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setCity(itemValue)}
                    >
                        {Object.keys(this.state.options).map((key) => {
                            return (<Picker.Item label={this.state.options[key]} value={key} key={key}/>) //if you have a bunch of keys value pair
                        })}
                    </Picker>

                    <Input icon={
                        <Icon
                            name='envelope-o'
                            color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'
                            size={25}
                            style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                        />
                    }

                           keyboardAppearance='light'
                           autoFocus={false}
                           autoCapitalize='none'
                           autoCorrect={false}
                           keyboardType='email-address'
                           returnKeyType='next'
                           inputStyle={{marginLeft: 10}}

                           containerStyle={{borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'}} placeholder="Subject" onChangeText={(title) => this.setTitle({title})}/>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{height: 40}}

                        placeholder="Type your text here!"
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setText({text})}
                    />
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.onPressLearnMore}

                        title="SUBMIT"
                        disabled={false}
                        titleStyle={{fontWeight: '700'}}
                        buttonStyle={{
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(92, 99,216, 1)',
                            width: 300,
                            height: 45,
                            borderColor: 'transparent',
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            borderRadius: 5
                        }}
                        containerStyle={{marginTop: 20}}
                    />

                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    contentView: {
        flex: 1
    },
    headerContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 40,
        backgroundColor: '#4F80E1',
        marginBottom: 20
    },
    heading: {
        color: 'white',
        marginTop: 10,
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
});

export default Buttons;
```

Comment: Can you please provide an mcve ? Also, add an 'l' to the end of the image url to resize it properly

Comment: i think you can give the header text absolute position and alignSelf as center and give the headerConatianer a width of device width. So that it moves to the center

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh I have resized the image. Thanks for the instruction.

Comment: @HarikrishnanS Can you please help me with the code for that? I am a beginner.